# How to write hook_field_placeholder_info() for the link module?

Tags: entities, 7

The contributed project
[**Field placeholder**](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_placeholder)
lets one use HTML5 placeholder attribute.  The project page says:

> By default, this module integrates text, number and mail modules,
>   but any other widget type can be added through
>   `hook_field_placeholder_info()`.

I've tested this with a “Text” field, and it works as advertised.

I want to add `hook_field_placeholder_info()` for the
[**Link**](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) module.

According to `field_placeholder.api.php`, this hook should return:

> An array whose keys are the widget names and whose value are the
>   widget item where the placeholder will be attached.

So far I've tried this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_placeholder_info().
 */
function mymodule_field_placeholder_info() {
  return array(
    'link_field' => 'value',
  );
}
```

This puts the widget for the placeholder settings on the admin page
where one manage the link file, but setting a placeholder value has no
effect when I create a new node with a link field.

I believe the problem is “`value`”.  According to the documentation,
it should be the “widget item where the placeholder will be attached”.

I am not sure what that is.  So far I've tried “`value`”, “`link_field`”,
 “`link`”,  and “`url`” (clearing the cache before testing each in
turn), but none of these work for the link field.

So: How to write hook_field_placeholder_info() for the link module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_placeholder/issues/2486785) to add support for the link module. Unfortunate that patch has not been committed yet, but you can use/apply the patch in [#5](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_placeholder/issues/2486785#comment-11979330) and use

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_placeholder_info().
 */
function mymodule_field_placeholder_info() {
  return array(
    'link_field' => 'url',
  );
}
```